# Asynchronously Load Firebase Database Before ('click')ing button

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble loading my firebase database before a user clicks a button and fires a function that filters and manipulates the data in my database. I have tried using a promise to asynchronously load the data, but to no avail.
You can look at my web app and see exactly what I'm talking about here: https://search-h2-b-employers.firebaseapp.com/

This is how I have tried to remedy this with a promise:

view:

```
<button class="button1" id="button1" (click)="addFire()">Try it</button>
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
ninjas: any;

fire(){
  firebase.database().ref('/H-2B_FY2016').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    this.ninjas.push(snapshot.val())
    });
}

  fetchData(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.fire)
    });
  }

}
```

component.ts:

```
addFire(){

  this.dataService.fetchData().then(this.myFunction())

     //myFunction() is the function that then filters and manipulates the firebase database. 
    //It ends up passing the data into a new array.
  }
```

I've tried all kinds of things and have gotten all kinds of errors from:

> cannot read property of 'ninjas' undefined"

to

> argument type any[] is not assignable to parameter type '(value: {}) => {} | PromiseLike<{}>'

This last one is the error I'm getting now.

Help would be greatly appreciate. Feel like I'm banging my head against a wall.